# Data loss during java serial communcation

Tags: java

I am trying to receive a telemetry string from arduino board to javafx apllication by jserialcomm.
My arduino output rate is about 100Hz now. in this situation i want to receive data in application about 1Hz. this is what i am doing:
This are only some important parts of code:

```
  Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              try {
                while (true) {
                  refresher(rx);
                  Thread.sleep(1000L);
                }
              } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
            }
          };
       Thread thr1 = new Thread(r1);
       thr1.start();




public void refresher(SerialPort rx){

                  readRX(rx);

    parseString(lastTelemetry);


}


private void readRX(SerialPort rx){
   Scanner ss = new Scanner(rx.getInputStream()); 
                    while(ss.hasNextLine()){
                        lastTelemetry = ss.nextLine();
                        if (lastTelemetry.isEmpty()) continue;
                        System.out.println(lastTelemetry);
                        break;
                    }
}
```

But the recieved string is not complete. some lines are complete and some or lost . this is what my output look like:

8,0,330,1306.42,86586.00,0,31.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,62.27,-6.81,4.53,0.00,00
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,66.24,-6.81,4.52,-0.30,00
1.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,70.22,-6.81,4.52,-0.10,00
7098,0,396,1306.33,86587.00,0,31.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,75.22,-6.81,4.51,-0.10,00

Comment: by data loss i mean they are not the same in length. i am not getting all comma seperated data.
all i want to do is to receive line every 1 second and parse and proccess it.

Comment: `1hz` is one cycle per second. I think you'd need to add clock discipline to the Arduino and line limit it (or maybe you could add a larger buffer on the host device).

Comment: i am not an expert:) can u explain a little more and how can i do that?

Comment: Only create your `Scanner` once (as @JimGarrison) points out below, and you can wrap the `InputStream` with a `BufferedInputStream` like `new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(rx.getInputStream(), 1024*32))` (for a 32k buffer, for example). As for [adding a clock](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-an-accurate-Arduino-clock-using-only-one-wire/), there are [several methods](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-and-why-to-add-a-real-time-clock-to-arduino/) you could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be creating a new input stream `new Scanner(rx.getInputStream())` every time you read input.  It is likely that if data is being buffered it is lost when you make a new stream.  Create the input stream once when you open the serial port and pass that as the parameter to the `readRX` method instead of the `SerialPort`.

Also, I couldn't find anything in a cursory read of the Javadoc where you specify the buffer size, or what happens if the buffer overflows.  That is another factor to consider.

Comment: Thanks  it seems it solved the problem but now after 4-5 line,i get out of boundary exception. i am working  on it right now. let me know if u have any idea for it too...
Any way Thanks man

Comment: You should ask a new question showing the updated code, and be sure to include the complete stack trace. Also, identify the line in your code that is throwing the exception.  If the exception is not in your code you may have to look through the stack to identify the line in your code that invoked a library method that threw the exception

Comment: Thanks i am working on it.. i will ask again if i couldnt solve it

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with the definition of hasNextLine().
See the following example:

```
byte[] data = "test".getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String text = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

There is no \n at the end or something like this. But it still outputs "test". So I expect you assume a different behaviour of the next line part.
Also es mentioned by someone else, cachine might be an additional failure source.

Comment: Maybe it behaves the same to end of text and \n in the example u said here